Proof of a generalisation of Kolmogorov's Inequality
A colleague and I need to use a generalisation of Kolmogorov's inequality given as Lemma 5.1 in the paper On Almost Sure Convergence by Michael Loève. We are having difficulty understanding the proof. I'll state it and give the proof here using modern notation and using $S_i$ rather than Loève's $U_i$ for the finite sums (which I think is standard in modern statements of Kolmogorov's inequality).
Statement: Let $X_1, \ldots, X_n$ be real random variables and assume that the conditional expectation $\mathbf{E}(X_i \mid X_1, \ldots, X_{i-1}) = 0$ with probability $1$, $1 \le i \le n$. Write $S_i = X_1 + \ldots + X_i$, $1 \le i \le n$. Then:
$$
\mathbf{P}[\sup_{1\le i \le n} |S_i| > \varepsilon] \le \frac{1}{\varepsilon^2}\mathbf{E}[S_n^2].
$$
Proof: Define events $A$, $A_i$ and $B_i$, $1 \le i \le n$ as follows:
\begin{align*}
A &= [\sup_{1\le i \le n} |S_i| > \varepsilon] \\
A_i &= [|S_i| > \varepsilon] \\
B_i &= A_1^c \cap \ldots \cap A_{i-1}^c \cap A_i.
\end{align*}
So, $A$ is the event whose probability we wish to bound and we have:
$$
A = \bigcup_{1\le i \le n}A_i = \bigsqcup_{1\le i \le n} B_i.
$$
The hypothesis yields:
$$
\mathbf{E}(S_n^2 \mid B_i) = \mathbf{E}(S_i^2 \mid B_i) + \mathbf{E}((S_n - S_i)^2 \mid B_i) \ge \varepsilon^2. \tag*{(*)}
$$
Consequently the desired inequality follows from:
$$
\mathbf{E}(S_n^2) \ge \sum_{1\le i \le n}\mathbf{P}(B_i)\mathbf{E}(S_n^2 \mid B_i) \ge \varepsilon^2\sum_{1\le i \le n}\mathbf{P}(B_i) = \varepsilon^2\mathbf{P}(A).
$$
It's the step I've labelled (*) that is baffling us. Clearly, as $S_n = S_i + (S_n - S_i)$, we can write:
\begin{align*}
\mathbf{E}(S_n^2 \mid B_i) &= \mathbf{E}(S_i^2 \mid B_i) + \mathbf{E}((S_n - S_i)^2 \mid B_i) + 2\mathbf{E}(S_i(S_n-S_i) \mid B_i) \\
&= \mathbf{E}(S_i^2 \mid B_i) + \mathbf{E}((S_n - S_i)^2 \mid B_i) + 2\sum_{\begin{array}{c}1 \le j \le i \\i < k \le n\end{array}}\mathbf{E}(X_jX_k \mid B_i).
\end{align*}
But how do we the use the hypothesis that $\mathbf{E}(X_i \mid X_1, \ldots, X_{i-1}) = 0$ with probability $1$, $1 \le i \le n$, to show that the third term on the right-hand side above vanishes?

Let $j\le i < k$.
Then the law of iterated expectation
$$
\mathbb E(X_j X_k\mid B_i)=\mathbb E\left[\mathbb E(X_j X_k\mid B_i,X_1,X_2,\dots,X_i)\mid B_i\right]
=\mathbb E\left[X_j \color{red}{\mathbb E(X_k\mid B_i,X_1,X_2,\dots,X_i)}\mid B_i\right]
$$
since $X_j$ is determined by $X_1,\dots,X_i$ and
$$
\color{red}{\mathbb E(X_k\mid B_i,X_1,X_2,\dots,X_i)}=
\mathbb E\left[\mathbb E(X_k\mid B_i,X_1,X_2,\dots,X_i,X_{i+1},\dots,X_{k-1})\mid B_i,X_1,X_2,\dots,X_i\right]=
\mathbb E\left[0\mid B_i,X_1,X_2,\dots,X_i\right]=0
$$
since $\mathbb E(X_k\mid  \sigma(X_1,\dots,X_{k-1})=0$.

Many thanks. I think you mean $j \le i < k$ in the first sentence, but this looks very promising. A tick will follow presently when I've internalised and agreed with the details.

The tick is yours. It looks spot on. Thanks again.
